# Painting with transparency issue

Tags: ios

I'm using CGLayers to implement a "painting" technique similar to Photoshop airbrush - and have run into something strange. When I use transparency and overpaint an area, the color never reaches full intensity (if the alpha value is below 0.5). My application uses a circular "airbrush" pattern with opacity fall off at the edges but I have reproduced the problem just using a semi-transparent white square. When the opacity level is less than 0.5, the overpainted area never reaches the pure white of the source layer. I probably wouldn't have noticed but I'm using the result of the painting as a mask, and not being able to get pure white causes problems. Any ideas what's going on here? Target iOS SDK 5.1.

Below is the resultant color after drawing the semi-transparent square many times over black background:

```
opacity color
------  -----
1.0     255
0.9     255
0.8     255
0.7     255
0.6     255
0.5     255
0.4     254
0.3     253
0.2     252
0.1     247
```

Simplified code that shows the issue:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef viewContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Create grey gradient to compare final blend color
    CGRect lineRect = CGRectMake(20, 20, 1, 400);
    float greyLevel = 1.0;
    for(int i=0;i<728;i++)
    {
        CGContextSetRGBFillColor(viewContext, greyLevel, greyLevel, greyLevel, 1);
        CGContextFillRect(viewContext, lineRect);
        lineRect.origin.x += 1;
        greyLevel -= 0.0001;
    }

    // Create semi-transparent white square
    CGSize whiteSquareSize = CGSizeMake(40, 40);
    CGLayerRef whiteSquareLayer = CGLayerCreateWithContext (viewContext, whiteSquareSize, NULL);
    CGContextRef whiteSquareContext = CGLayerGetContext(whiteSquareLayer);
    CGContextSetAlpha(whiteSquareContext, 1.0f); // just to make sure
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(whiteSquareContext, 1, 1, 1, 0.3); // ??? color never reaches pure white if alpha < 0.5
    CGRect whiteSquareRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, whiteSquareSize.width, whiteSquareSize.height);
    CGContextFillRect(whiteSquareContext, whiteSquareRect);

    // "Paint" with layer a bazillion times
    CGContextSetBlendMode(viewContext, kCGBlendModeNormal); // just to make sure
    CGContextSetAlpha(viewContext, 1.0); // just to make sure
    for(int strokeNum=0;strokeNum<100;strokeNum++)
    {
        CGPoint drawPoint = CGPointMake(0, 400);
        for(int x=0;x<730;x++)
        {
            CGContextDrawLayerAtPoint(viewContext, drawPoint, whiteSquareLayer);
            drawPoint.x++;
        }
    }
}
```